# nodjs installation fail - repodata/repomd.xml not found

Tags: centos7, node.js

I am trying to install nodejs on vagrant box https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7/versions/1905.1

I am getting following repo not found response. 
It is trying to look for http://yum.puppetlabs.com/latest/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml which does not exist not sure from where it got configured. its new machine only have puppet-agent-6.6.0 running.

Can you advise how to fix it?

```
==> default: Error: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install nodejs' returned 1: One of the configured repositories failed (Puppet Labs latest Repository),
==> default:  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
==> default:  safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
==> default: 
==> default:      1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
==> default: 
==> default:      2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
==> default:         upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
==> default:         distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
==> default:         packages for the previous distribution release still work).
==> default: 
==> default:      3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
==> default:             yum --disablerepo=pc_repo ...
==> default: 
==> default:      4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
==> default:         will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
==> default:         again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
==> default: 
==> default:             yum-config-manager --disable pc_repo
==> default:         or
==> default:             subscription-manager repos --disable=pc_repo
==> default: 
==> default:      5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
==> default:         Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
==> default:         so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
==> default:         slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
==> default:         compromise:
==> default: 
==> default:             yum-config-manager --save --setopt=pc_repo.skip_if_unavailable=true
==> default: 
==> default: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pc_repo: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
==> default: http://yum.puppetlabs.com/latest/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation of https://forge.puppet.com/stahnma/epel and include it before nodejs fix the problem.

mod 'stahnma-epel', '1.3.1'
include '::epel'